# EF code first iterates over all properties while creating object

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I use EF Code First in my application and have the following class:

```
   [Table("TBL_XYZ")]
    public class XYZ
    {
        [Required]
        public string PropA { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int PropB  { get; set; }

        public int FormulaA 
        {
          get 
          {
            return PropB *  Math.PI / 100;
          }
        }
    }
```

This is how I get the data from the database:

```
var data = (from e in db.XYZ where e.PropB < 100 select e).ToList();
```

After I added some more fields which do calculations and don't have a set accessor (like FormulaA), I realized a drop in performance when executing the above line.

After some debugging I found out that EF iterates over all Properties.  It calls all get-functions of the properties, while creating the object, even if I don't access them.

What is the purpose of this behaviour and is there a workaround. Does this maybe have something to do with keeping track of changes?
It is really convenient for me to have my formulas in the object itself, but right now it severely affects the performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add

```
[NotMapped]
public int FormulaA ....
```

And also in query select only properties what you really need.

```
select new {e.PropA, e.PropB}
```

Comment: The NotMapped attribute is a good idea. But I also have some Properties which are formulas and also should be stored in the database; that wouldn't work with NotMapped.

Comment: Interesting case. What about second variant and initializing your type only with loaded data?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand "initializing your type only with loaded data"? Do you mean something like "select new {e.PropA, e.PropB}"?

Comment: Yes, at first load only PropA,PropB to anonymous type and after that convert to object of your type. ...Select(x => new XYZ(x.PropA, x.PropB)). Something like that, but I'm not sure that will be faster :)

Comment: I really appreciate your help. But there is another problem: my classes have A LOT of properties (around 100) and I don't want to list all of them. What's more important I don't want to add properties at different places in my code everytime I add a new property (which is going to happen in the future).